# How do I use a linked cell in Excel in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

I am trying to create a formula using a cell that holds data linked from another tab in the same spreadsheet.  When the source cell is blank, the linked cell shows "0".   Is there a way to have the linked cell show up as blank instead of showing "0"?  I am having trouble using the cell showing "0" in other formulas.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use ISBLANK.

```
=if(ISBLANK(A1), "", formula)
```

Replace A1 with your reference cell and formula with what you want this cell to contain if A1 isn't blank.

Comment: @Sarah if this answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it

Answer (score 2):

Use the code =If(IsBlank(sheetname!cellnumber),"",sheetname!cellnumber)
and where sheetname is Sheet1,Sheet2, etc, and cellnumber is A1,A2,B5,etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(CELLNAME=0, "", CELLNAME)
```

Replace `CELLNAME` with the actual name of the cell you're referencing.